# Android app for website

Tags: android, web-services, web, webview

Hi I want to develop an app for website but show the site design without any changes I mean not just a simple webview in my activity actually I'm looking for a tutorial about it and i couldn't find any on the Internet
Can any one help me please

An example of what I mean is like Stackexchange android app

Comment: Write an app using design cues from the existing website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest starting with the Android webapp documentation at the link below:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html

Here is a link to some documentation on how to do some basic things in a web app such as adding a web view and page navigation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html